# Powershell Expression gives no results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have created an expression that should return the OU canonical name. A small outline:

```
@(Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly) | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,@{Name="OU";Expression={((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $($_."DistinguishedName")).CanonicalName)}}
```

However, this expression returns an empty OU column, the other 2 columns are filled.

My question is what is wrong with this expression? Any feedback is appreciated.

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Comment: at what step in your pipeline does the process fail to do as you expect? **_do it manually with one known account & one step at a time to find out._**

Comment: The OU from the second part does not return a result, only an empty column. There is no error message.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to wrap your `Search-ADAccount` call in `@(...)` - if the call happens to return only a _single_ object, it is still properly sent through the pipeline.

Comment: Also: `$($_."DistinguishedName")` can be simplified to `$_.DistinguishedName`

Comment: Why would you even use `Search-ADAccount` for this? Just do `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!lockedOut=0)" -Properties CanonicalName`.

Comment: @TheStingPilot - so this `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $($_."DistinguishedName")` returns NOTHING when you send it a valid `Search-ADAccount` object that contains a valid distinguished name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're trying to feed `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` a user's `DistinguishedName` instead of an OU's `DistinguishedName` which is not valid.

It's also worth mentioning, you're missing `-Properties CanonicalName` on `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`.

Try this instead:

```bash
$exp = { ($_.DistinguishedName.Split(',', 2)[1] | Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName }
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{ N = "OU"; E = $exp }
```

Now, this syntax using calculated properties with `Select-Object` above is really hard to read but also very inefficient, it is querying the OUs per every user and there is a very high chance that the same OU will be queried more than once. What I would recommend instead is to cache the OUs in a hashtable with `key = the OU DN` and `value = the OU CanonicalName`.

This is much better:

```bash
$cache = @{}
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly | ForEach-Object {
    $ouDN = $_.DistinguishedName.Split(',', 2)[1]

    if (-not $cache.ContainsKey($ouDN)) {
        $ou = $ouDN | Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName
        $cache[$ouDN] = $ou.CanonicalName
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name           = $_.Name
        SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
        OU             = $cache[$ouDN]
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the sleuthing and the simple solution, but, unfortunately, it isn't _robust_, because DN values may contain _escaped_ `,` characters (`\,`), which need to be recognized as such.

Comment: @mklement0 I agree it isn't a robust solution, though, it is a really very bad practice to have AD Objects with a comma on their `commonName` which is why I recommended this simple split over the `distinguishedName`.

Comment: While it may be better to _avoid_  escaped `,` chars., I wouldn't call it bad practice, given that the very existence of an escape mechanism implies that `,` characters in values _are_ supported. Therefore, the limitation of your solution should be explicitly stated.

Comment: That works out-of-the-box. Very impressive. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TheStingPilot happy to help, if you see that `commonNames` with a `,` on them is allowed by your IAM team you might want to consider the regex solution proposed by mklement0.

Answer (score 3):

A **troubleshooting technique for calculated properties**:

The script block stored in the `Expression` entry of a hashtable defining a  [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

- runs in a *child* scope relative to the caller's scope.
- more importantly, it *quietly ignores any errors* that occur.

However, such errors *are* recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), so to diagnose your problem you can do the following:

```sh
$Error.Clear()

Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly | 
  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{Name="OU";Expression={(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $_.DistinguishedName).CanonicalName}}

$Error # Output the errors that occurred inside the calculated property's script block.
```

---

**Solution to your specific problem**:

As [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69989948/45375) explains, you need to extract the *OU*'s distinguished name (DN) from the *user's* and pass the former to `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity`.

While `$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',',2)[1]`, which removes the first `,`-separated token from the user's DN will *typically* work, it can fail with DNs that use *escaped* `,` chars. (`\,`) that are to be treated as part of a value; e.g.:

```sh
# !! Simple splitting by the first "," is NOT enough here:
PS> 'CN=Martin Luther King\, Jr.,OU=Ministry,DC=example,DC=org'.Split(',',2)[1]

 Jr.,OU=Ministry,DC=example,DC=org # !! WRONG - split at the *escaped* ","
```

To also handle these edge cases, i.e. **to *robustly* extract the OU's DN from a user's**, a sophisticated [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) is required, in combination with the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

```sh
# OK: The regex correctly recognizes the escaped \, as such.
PS> 'CN=Martin Luther King\, Jr.,OU=Ministry,DC=example,DC=org' -replace '^.+?((?<=[^\\])(?:\\\\)*),'

OU=Ministry,DC=example,DC=org  # OK
```

To put it all together:

```sh
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly | 
  Select-Object Name, 
                SamAccountName, 
                @{
                  Name = 'OU'
                  Expression = {
                    (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity ($_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.+?((?<=[^\\])(?:\\\\)*),')).CanonicalName
                  }
                }
```