# Switch Statement Not Processing all conditions: Check if OU Exists

Tags: powershell, active-directory, organizational-unit

I am attempting to use a switch to test different OUs for a matching location code OU which will cause a computer to moved to be moved into a child OU of the OUs I'm searching. A Location Code will only exist in one OU. So I'm checking to see if that OU exists via adsi.exists() which will return true when the location OU is found in each search location The problem is my switch seems to only evaluate the first condition and then moves on out of the switch. I'm not sure why this is happening, can anyone please advise?

**What I expect:** I expect each condition in the switch will be evaluate until one matches TRUE then the code associated with that match will be executed, moving my PC to the correct place in my directory.

Am I better served just doing if/else?

```
$LocationCode = $this.PCName.split("-")[0]
        
        try{
            $PCDC = (Get-ADComputer $this.PCName).DistinguishedName
            $FoundLCInOU = $true
            Switch ($FoundLCInOU) {
                # Check for location Code in Stores
                ([adsi]::Exists("OU DN")){
                    Write-Host " This computer belongs to the Location 1"
                }
                # Check for location code in CustomerExperienceCenter
                ([adsi]::Exists("OU DN")){
                    Write-Host "This Computer blongs to the Location 2"
                }
                # Check for location code in CAF
                ([adsi]::Exists("OU DN")){
                    Write-Host "This Computer Belongs to Location 3"
                }
                # Check for location code in HomeOffice 
                ([adsi]::Exists("OU DN")){
                    Write-Host "This computer belongs to the Location 4"
                }
            } catch {
                Write-Host "Couldn't find a home for this PC, just keep swimming..."
            }
```

Comment: Yu code is always checking for same condition so only one case will exist with other being optimized out.

Comment: @jdweng how can that be when each ADSI:Exists() check is checking for a a location code in a different OU. Each Statement to evaluate is unique even if I am only check true/false. so I'm not sure why the other locations would be optimized out. Can you help me understand better?

Comment: Every case has [adsi]::Exists("OU DN")

Comment: @jdweng So to make sure I understand, Because powershell sees that each condition is an instance of the adsi class, it's saying "Oh, these are all the same conditions, I'm done with this" because I'm not making the ADSI instance unique, rather I'm just calling a function of that class) so it thinks all those conditions are the same since it sees the same class as the last condition?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3#examples

Comment: seems like you want to evaluate with a scriptblock: `switch ($thing) { { <# script block condition #> } { <# if true, this happens #> } ... }`

Comment: @jdweng - powershell's ```switch``` *doesn't* exit after the first matching conditional - it continues to evaluate all subsequent case expressions and runs *all* that match - for example ```switch( 1 ) { 1 { write-host "first" } 1 { write-host "second" } 2 { write-host "third" } }``` will output ```first second```, not just ```first``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3 where it says "The switch statement is equivalent to a series of if statements,"

Comment: The code you wrote seems a bit weird to me. The switch statement is used to check the equality of the test expression to several cases. In your case the text expression is `$true` and you are checking whether the cases evaluate to `$true`. Although semantically correct, using a `if/else` statement would be more appropriate.

Comment: @C.Aknesil the intention is that the switch will check distinct locations OUs for a child OU that matches a specific location code, since there is only one location code possible this allows me to take action on the switch statement that is true, then BREAK out of the switch to continue the function. To me, this seems cleaner than a bunch of if if/else blocks. but I'm a self-taught programmer so my code is probably a little out there.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comments, based on the current state of the code in your question:

- The input to your [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement is a *static* value, `$true`.
- Your branch conditionals are *all the same*, `([adsi]::Exists("OU DN"))`.
- In other words: you're not performing any operation related to the variable information stored in `$LocationCode` and `$PCDC`.
- Generally, `switch` evaluates *all* branch conditionals, even after finding a match (the special `Default` branch is only executed
  if none of the other branches matched).

  - To *stop* further evaluation, use either `continue` or `break`:
  - `break` and `continue` work the same for *single-value* input (as in this case), but differ in meaning for *array-valued* input (see below for an example): `continue` moves on to the next array element, whereas `break` stops processing altogether.
- Therefore, the behavior of your statement depends on the return value of the [`[adsi]::Exists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Exists) call: if `$true`, *all* branches are executed; if `$false`, none are.
- Note that while using an *expression* such as your method call as a branch conditional works, the more flexible (albeit slower) approach is to use a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }` inside of which you can refer to the input value at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), call arbitrary commands, and output (what possibly implicitly evaluates to)  `$true` or `$false` to signal a match or non-match; a simple example:

  ```bash
    # Note: Each element of the input array is processed separately.
    switch ('one', 'two', 'eight') { 
      # Matches inputs 'one' and 'two', but not 'eight'
      { $_.Length -eq 3 } { "Value is 3 chars. long: $_" }
    }
  ```

  - In other words:

    - Using an *expression* fundamentally works the same as using a *literal* in that the expression *result* must match the input value; e.g. with input `'foo'`, an example of an expression equivalent of a literal `'foo'` conditional would be `('f' + 'oo')`
    - By contrast, using a *script block* allows you to perform arbitrary operations and signal a match via a *Boolean* result.

      - If a given `switch` statement ends up having *only* script-block conditionals, it still offers *some* advantages over an equivalent `if` / `elseif` / `else` statement, namely:

        - `switch`'s support for *array*-valued input (by implicitly processing *each element*) saves you from creating a loop explicitly.
        - A dynamically calculated input needn't be assigned to an aux. variable, given that `switch` makes the value available via the automatic `$_` variable.

---

Not knowing your true requirements, here's an example of a more meaningful `switch` statement; for simplicity, it tests the `$LocationCode` value against known strings:

```bash
try {
  $PCDC = (Get-ADComputer -ErrorAction Stop $this.PCName).DistinguishedName
  $locationCode = $this.PCName.split('-')[0]
  switch ($locationCode) {
    'Stores' {
      'This computer belongs to the Location 1'
      continue  # short-circuit
    }
    'CustomerExperienceCenter' {
      'This Computer blongs to the Location 2'
      continue  # short-circuit
    }
    'CAF' {
      'This Computer Belongs to Location 3'
      continue  # short-circuit
    }
    # Check for location code in HomeOffice 
    'HomeOffice' {
      'This computer belongs to the Location 4'
      continue  # short-circuit
    }
    Default {
      Write-Warning "Unknown location code: $locationCode"
    }
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Warning "Couldn't find a home for this PC, just keep swimming..."
}
```

Note:

- If your real intent is to extract the OU name from the computer's distinguished name and then test whether such an OU actually exists, you can use the techniques shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982023/45375).